# Trying to build Latex document in sublime gives Java error

Tags: java, latex, sublimetext3

I'm trying to compile a simple latex using LaTexTools package, and when I press cmd-B, I get the following error. I've googled this error and all the answers I've read have to do with java files, which I don't have here. I'm not sure how I should go about fixing this.

```
Error: Could not find or load main class test
[Finished in 0.1s with exit code 1]
[cmd: ['java', 'test']]
[dir: /Users/Username/Desktop]
[path: /Users/Username/Projects/reedsnotes/google-cloud-sdk/bin:/Users/Username/opt/anaconda3/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin:/usr/local/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/TeX/texbin:/opt/X11/bin]
```

Comment: In the `Tools > Build System` menu, which build system has a checkmark next to it?

Comment: ah that was the problem, thank you.